# Vuetify - How to access data in form rule

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

Can I access a data element in a `rule`?

[Here is my code running](https://bc-only-rates-trimakas.c9users.io/)

I'm trying to flip the value of a `data` element on a text field rule in a Vuetify form.

The rule itself works fine, however I'm unable to access the data element, I'm getting this error:

`TypeError: Cannot set property 'disabled' of undefined`

Here is my code:

```
data: function() {
return {
  disabled: false,
  rules:{
    sellerId(value){
      if(value.length == 0){
        this.disabled = true;
        return "What are you trying to do here?";  
      }
      else{
        return true;
      }
    }
  },
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: could you provide a pen contains some of your code?

Comment: Here is the app actually running. https://bc-only-rates-trimakas.c9users.io/ I'm thinking you can see my code in the console.

Comment: What do you mean by 'flip the value'?

Comment: `this` isn't available to a rule in vuetify.  What are you trying to do?  Maybe better to disable on the validation result somehow?

Comment: you could also use computed property like in this example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eQGvxV?editors=1111

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`rules` are an array of functions, and if you need the function to be able to access `data` property, you can define them as component methods:

```
data: function () {
  return {
    disabled: false
  }
},
methods: { 
  sellerId (value) {
    if (value.length === 0) {
      this.disabled = true;
      return "What are you trying to do here?";  
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

And then in your `Vuetify` component:

```
<v-text-field :rules="[ sellerId ]"></v-text-field>
```

Comment: Isn't it better to define the function as computed to use cache benefits ?

Comment: Thanks! Also curious for the question asked by @Alizadeh118.

Comment: The rule function will be called on change, blur, etc. You don't need cache.

Comment: Solution is perfect

Comment: I've found out it does not work with computed prop properly - function has to be called on every change, and there are some problems with mentioned cache i think. Use methods instead :)

Answer (score 4):

While `this` isn't available to a rule function you can accomplish this by assigning the vue instance to a variable, which will bring it into scope by closure.

```
vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: () => ({
        disabled: true,
        rules: [
            value => {
                if (value.length == 0) {
                    vm.disabled = true;
                    return "What are you trying to do here?";  
                }
                else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        ],
'''
```

Answer (score 4):

try to define `rules` as `computed` property :

```
data: function() {
    return {
      disabled: false,
      ...
    }
  },
  computed: {
    sellerIdRules() {
      return [
         (v) => {
        if (value.length == 0) {
          this.disabled = true;
          return "What are you trying to do here?";
        } else {
          return true;
        } ]
      }
    }
  }
```