# How to access data that has already been validated?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, validation, vuetify.js

Is it possible to take the data that was validated after the validation context?

```js
<template>
  <v-text-field
    :rules="[rules.required]"
    @change='doSomething($event)'
  ></v-text-field>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      rules: {
        required: v => !!v || 'Field required.'
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    doSomething (value) {
      // does something only if the data is validated
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

In this situation, I need to work with the data that has gone through the validation stage of the field and is valid.

I do not know how to do this in vuetify, but is there any way to get this data without having to by a function within the validation rules to do this?

Comment: this might help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366501/vuetify-how-to-access-data-in-form-rule

Comment: adding a function inside the validation rules, only this way is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could listen the `updated:error` event and when the value received is `false` go your call.

```
<template>
 <v-text-field
  :rules="[rules.required]"
  @update:error='doSomething'
 ></v-text-field>
```

And in the script

```
methods: {
 doSomething (error) {
   if (error === false) {
     // model is validated
   }
 }
}
```

To access the fields value you should use `v-model`.

Comment: I tested this example and it did not work. I understand that the change in type of error will be heard, so I want to run the event only if the data is valid and not in case of error

Comment: You get an update when the error is updated. With a value of false it means that the validation passed

Comment: I tried to formulate an example equal to what was explained and it did not work, [here is the link](https://gist.github.com/carvalhoviniciusluiz/bf3db74edb4b69bebb766ad46135ac7e)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/djshan/pen/LaXxYR?editors=1010), the submit button does not work until the `firstname` field is valid. You can also remove `lazy-validation` so the button will not be clickable until it has met the validation rules.

```
<v-form
  ref="form"
  v-model="valid"
  lazy-validation
>
  <v-text-field
    v-model="firstname"
    :rules="nameRules"
    label="Firstname"
    required
  ></v-text-field>

  <v-btn
    :disabled="!valid"
    color="success"
    @click="doSomething"
  >
    Submit
  </v-btn>
</v-form>
```

And here is the script part:

```
<script>
  export default {
     data () {
       return {
         valid: true,
         firstname: '',
         nameRules: [v => !!v || 'Name is required']
     }
    },
    methods: {
       doSomething () {
          if (this.$refs.form.validate()) {
                 console.log(this.firstname);

          }


       },

    }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: let's say you had to send the information in the blur event of the field whenever the user put something new, only the valid data should be sent. What would such a thing be like?

Comment: @ViníciusCarvalho so you want to delay validation until blur event?

Comment: I really want to send the data that is in the field to an API only if the value is valid with the rules of the field. I believe the blur event is ideal for this but I need to know if the data has passed the validation so I can send it

Comment: you can add `validate-on-blur` to your `v-text-field`.